# Understanding the use of a truthy/falsy variable as a test condition in a while loop

Tags: javascript

The concept of using variables as a while loop test condition is a little confusing to me:

```
const falsy = "";
while (falsy) {
    console.log(1);
}
```

From what I understand, the test condition 'falsy' doesn't refer to the constant 'falsy' but rather, in it's expanded form, is something like: 'while (falsy === true) {...}'. In this case, since falsy (the constant) evaluates to false, the statement becomes 'while (false === true){...}' which makes the test condition false and the block not execute.

What confuses me is that 'falsy' in the test condition seems to address to two things:

1. It refers to the actual **constant 'falsy'** and uses that to evaluate truthiness/falsiness of the test condition
2. It represents the **condition that needs to be satisfied** (i.e. falsy as the test condition is testing whether falsy (the constant) is true)

Can anyone confirm my understanding regarding the use of truthy/falsy variables for test conditions?

Comment: The condition is an *expression* which when evaluated as a Boolean value is either truthy or falsey. Any value and any expression can be coerced into a Boolean value.

Comment: MDN is a good source for documentation [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). It doesn't matter what your variable is named; you could have said `const falsy = true;` at the top, and it would still evaluate the loop body.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference is between 1 and 2. The condition that needs to be satisfied is that the variable `falsy` contains a truthy value.

Comment: @Barmar In 1. I'm saying that falsy represents the constant defined that is evaluated to a Boolean value. In 2. I'm saying that there is also a condition being evaluated here (i.e. falsy === true?). I believe what's lost on me is the fact that the syntax is concise to the point where, in my mind, there are two distinct things happening here but they're not distinctly represented.

Comment: That's just what `while` does -- it evaluates the expression as a truthy value each time to see if it should continue the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Understood. Perhaps another example would better illustrate my point: while (i < 5){...}. The distinction between variable and test condition are clearly shown. i, which evaluates to whatever we've defined it as and '< 5' the test condition. In contrast, using a test condition like while(falsy)... seems to combine these two aspects

Comment: It's really unclear what your not understanding, your maybe over complicating things in your head.  `while(something)`,  here something has to be a boolean, if it's not a boolean then JS will force it into a boolean.  `x < 5` is a boolean, so JS does nothing here.  `falsy = ""` is NOT a boolean, so JS will coerse it into one, with js an implicit conversion of `""` == false.

Comment: I think you are confused because there is no operator in the expression. If you're new to programming and every if/while/for statement you've seen has always had an operator used, then this would appear strange. Think of `while()` as a *function* where the first argument must be *boolean*. JavaScript will always pass a *boolean* value to *while* and will do coercion to something no matter what. The general rule is, if no value can be converted to boolean then false will be passed. For example; `while(NaN) {}` will be false.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript has *implicit* coercion, in this case one happens to `Boolean`. It is not equivalent to `while (falsy === true)`, but closer to `while (Boolean(falsy))`.

See [the MDN glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) for the rules.

For example, the following would not print 1 if the test was `x === true`, however, we say that *«x is truthy»* because `Boolean(x)` **is** `true`.

```js
const x = ":)";
if (x) {
  console.log(1);
}
console.info("To demonstrate,", x === true, Boolean(x));
```